# Autocomplete Jquery Multiple Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, rows, multiple-columns

I have a table with multiple rows and columns and I don't know how to use the Autocomplete plugin of Jquery, in order to autocomplete only the row selected. It is the table code:

```
<table class="participante estilizar" id="participante_<?php echo $i?>" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="cedula">Cédula</label><input class="cedula" onkeypress="return numeros(event)" type="text" maxlength="50" name="participante_cedula[]" value="<?php echo $value->cedula?>" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="nombre">Nombre y apellido</label><input class="nombre" onkeypress="return alfa(event)" type="text" maxlength="75" name="participante_nombre[]" value="<?php echo $value->nombre?>" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="correo">Correo</label><input class="correo" type="text" maxlength="50" name="participante_correo[]" value="<?php echo $value->correo?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I know that I should use tag id to identify each row of my table, but in this case I don't know how to call Autocomplete plugin. It is the autocomplete code:

```
var sug_cedula = [
    {
        label: "123",
        nombre: "Juan",
        correo: "juan@cuenta.com"
    },
    {
        label: "456",
        nombre: "Pedro",
        correo: "pedro@cuenta.com"
    },
    {
        label: "789",
        nombre: "Angel",
        correo: "angel@cuenta.com"
    }
];
$( ".cedula" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: sug_cedula,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( ".cedula" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $( ".nombre" ).val( ui.item.nombre );
        $( ".correo" ).val( ui.item.correo );
        return false;
    }, 
});
```

In my example when I type some char and select an option, the function autocompletes all the table with the same values because I'm using tag class and not tag id. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to set the current values for the current row, you can do:

```
$( ".cedula" ).autocomplete({
   minLength: 0,
   source: sug_cedula,
   focus: function( event, ui ) {
       return false;
   },
   select: function( event, ui ) {
    var thisRow = $(this).parents("tr");
    thisRow.find(".cedula").val( ui.item.label );
    thisRow.find(".nombre").val( ui.item.nombre );
    thisRow.find(".correo").val( ui.item.correo );
    return false;
   }, 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, indeed it works for me, I only had to add this code before use your option: `code` var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');